# Javascript contains double quotes in variable for clipboard

Tags: javascript, html, variables, double-quotes

This script is working for normal string.

```
var dummyContent = "test string";
var dummy = $('<textarea>').val(dummyContent).appendTo('body').select();
document.execCommand('copy');
$(dummy).remove();
```

I wanna copy PHP codes to clipboard. But this script not working. For example:

```
var dummyContent = "function printsomething(){
echo "something";
}
printsomething();";

var dummy = $('<textarea>').val(dummyContent).appendTo('body').select();
document.execCommand('copy');
$(dummy).remove();
```

Comment: What do you expect the paste to be? Does [this help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript)?

Comment: Escape double quotes `var dummyContent = "function printsomething(){ echo \"something\"; } printsomething();";` or use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: This way working perfectly !!!